# How to stop a scheduled function cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have used 
 
`this->schedule(schedule_selector(MyNode::TickMe), 0, 0, 0);`

to call a function whenever the player touches the screen.

But I want that as soon as the player stops touching the screen, the scheduled function also stops i.e. dont call the function TickMe anymore.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT::**
Okay I got it. There is unschedule function available in CCNode. 
(Solved)

Comment: I though it would be helpful for others to let it be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//unschedule the function.

unschedule(schedule_selector(MyNode::TickMe));
```

Comment: i got error "cannot take the address of an rvalue of type void"

Answer (score 0):

```
this->unschedule(schedule_selector(MyNode::TickMe));
```

where `this` is an instance of `MyNode` which is a subclass of `Node`